# Plausible Reason for Asteroids Being Close Together

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, space, asteroids

I know that in real life, asteroids tend to be hundreds of thousands of kilometres apart.

In fiction, asteroids are often very close together, maybe a few hundred metres. Obviously this is much more exciting.

In the short story I'm writing, I want to include a battle scene set in a dense asteroid field like the one in "The Empire Strikes Back".

This leads me to my question: is there any scientifically plausible reason for the existence of an asteroid field or belt containing millions of asteroids tightly packed together?

Comment: Hello Anonymous! Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and read through our [help] to better understand and make full use of the site.

Comment: Do they have to be *asteroids*? Ringo's *absolutely amazing* [Troy Rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Ringo_bibliography#Troy_Rising) series has some scenes (albeit not battles) set in the wreckage left after major fleet battles. Maybe that would work for you?

Comment: There is only one plausible reason: Star Wars Reenactment. In the far future people will be rich (compared to us) beyond belief and have so much free time that even the most bizarre hobbies will be mainstream. In such a universe, there will be people who reenact Star Wars (but probably not the prequels, they're shit). Obviously asteroids will have to be towed into place so that the Millennium Falcon replica can try to escape the TIE fighters within the field. The alien creatures will be animatronic, since genetically engineering womp rats would be considered unethical...

Comment: Wasn't that dense asteroid field simply the rubble from the recently-destroyed Alderaan, or am I misremembering?

Answer (score 18):

We need look no further than [Saturn's rings](https://www.space.com/23235-rings-of-saturn.html).

> Saturn's rings are made up of billions of particles ranging from grains of sand to mountain-size chunks.

Pioneer 11 [passed through the outer rings](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/722/pioneer-11-at-saturn/) and although it came close to hitting one of the two new moons it discovered, it survived, suggesting that the density of the outer rings is low enough to not give you the effect you're looking for. However, I believe the density of the inner rings are. The Cassini probe discovered evidence that there may be [millions of moonlets in the rings](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/jan/31/saturns-rings-contain-millions-moonlets-new-nasa-images-reveal-cassini). That suggests mountain-sized to me.

**So, can we have a large field like in the *Empire Strikes Back*?**

Of course we can. But there are some caveats.

1. Gravity is not your friend. When you get mountain-sized asteroids in close proximity, gravity wants to pull them together to form planets. This process takes a honking long time — but it's nevertheless going on. So why doesn't Saturn's rings coalesce? Because the gravity of Saturn and the orbit of the rings keep them churned up like a food mixer.
2. All that cool flying around in *The Empire Strikes Back,* without the use of Star-Trek-grade "inertial dampers" would turn most passengers on a space ship into a thin pink marmalade on the side of a bulkhead. [This cool bit of space math](https://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/weekly/10Page28.pdf) points out that the orbital speeds of Saturn's rings are up to 24 Km/s.  That doesn't sound like much until you convert it into Km/h (86,400 Km/h or Mach 70). This means you need a lot more space between those asteroids to give you maneuvering room than the folks at Lucasfilm led us to believe. So if you want "real," you're not actually looking for what the film did. You need the asteroids spread out much more (there'd still be plenty of high-stress flying around!).

I don't believe we know yet of any such fields outside planetary rings, but we're only just beginning to view our galaxy with detail. That being said, I can think of no reason why they can't. In fact, I think for the sake of a story it would be very plausible to find them in or around nebulae or orbiting newly-formed stars.

Comment: While the orbital speed of Saturn's ring are quite high, the relative speed between objects is far lower - and it is this speed that determines how difficult it is to maneuver.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen That's a good point - but it's incomplete and misleading. I may need to only move 1 Km/s relative to the asteroids, but I'm still moving at 25 Km/s. The G-force of that turn isn't based on relative speed.

Comment: Note that Star Wars _also_ has inertial dampers, presumably for the same reasons.

Comment: @JBH, no, but the size of turn needed *is* based on relative speed.  A maneuver that looks like a 90-degree left turn in the 1 km/s ring-relative reference frame is just a 2.3-degree radial-inward turn in the 25 km/s Saturn-relative reference frame.

Comment: @Mark that's true, but what's the point? I'm not going to dig up the math, but there's a minimum arc a human can survive without blacking out vs. G-force. That force is dictated by the actual velocity, not the relative velocity. All you and Klaus are pointing out is that to an inexperienced pilot a turn around an asteroid might *look* simple, but won't actually be due to the G-forces involved. Just because you're moving slowly compared to the asteroids doesn't mean you won't black out due to very real, actual velocity.

Comment: @JBH There's no such thing as "actual velocity". All velocity is relative. And, yes, if you're moving slowly compared to the asteroids, you can turn as tight as you want without excessive G forces, regardless of your velocity relative to Saturn.

Comment: @JBH the Earth is also orbiting the sun at 107,000km/h, by your logic, if I'm running in a straight line and change direction by 90 degrees at a street corner, I should experience a G-force strong enough to squish my body into a pancacke. The fact this doesn't happen should show why the orbital velocity of Saturn's rings is equally irrelevant

Comment: Also, apart from the g-force part, this is the best answer

Comment: Saturn rings are pretty [new](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-46911945), are [disappering](https://www.cbsnews.com/video/saturn-rings-disappearing-nasa-2019-08-06/), [forming new moons](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/886/cassini-finds-saturns-rings-coat-tiny-moons/#:~:text=New%20findings%20have%20emerged%20about,of%20Saturn's%20larger%20moon%20Enceladus.) and even their main moons are new objects. The fact we can observe Saturn rings is amazing [or a miracle].

Comment: @FredStark: While I upvoted your comment, I'd point that the orbital velocity of the rings do matter. If you're standing "still" and asteroids are coming at you at 24km/s it's a hell of a dodge ball game that you're playing. As a result, any pilot getting into the rings will probably have an incentive to match the ring speed to a degree, if only to decrease the relative velocity of objects in the ring compared to its vessel so as to have time to dodge them.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you very definitely won't be "standing still". If you're orbiting Saturn, you'll be nearly still relative to the asteroids and have plenty of time to dodge. If you're doing a flyby, you'll be moving at Saturn's escape velocity - not orbital velocity - relative to Saturn.  Best case, your relative velocity would be (escape velocity - orbital velocity). Not sure how those relate numerically.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: Given that the vessels in Star Wars were not orbiting anything, I don't think we should expect to be orbiting Saturn here. In any case, you could be orbiting in the opposite direction as the current rings, in which asteroids are coming your way at 48 km/s...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Presumably anyone entering Saturn's orbit would know about that possibility, and actively decide whether to get into that situation or not.

Answer (score 15):

Make the field a very recent creation. Say a planetoid was recently captured by the planet and torn apart because it's orbit was inside the Roche limit; just enough time has elapsed to break it's pieces into a nice debris field, but not enough for collisions and orbital decay to make it too sparse. You would of course be cherry picking a rather brief window of time (astronomically speaking,) but what interesting story isn't?

Comment: Since we are looking at Star Wars universe (or alike), there was a nice little thing that can generate a lot of rocky debris in little time. It just needed one planet as input and no pesky kids dropping bombs down the vents.

Answer (score 6):

**Trojans might help suspend disbelief**

Asteroids are collected at the Lagrange points of planets, in our system notably the [Trojan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_trojan) points of Jupiter. While they are *still* not dense enough, a soft SF story might mention that the battle happens "in a dense patch of the trailing (or leading) Trojan point."

Alternatively, consider going to the [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_of_Saturn) of a gas giant. Again less dense as you want, probably, and it might not contain sufficiently large rocks.

Answer (score 2):

**The asteroids carry electrical charge.**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHrBhgwq__Q

[image: water droplets and a knitting needles]

This great video from the space station shows droplets of water orbiting a charged knitting needle.  Rather than the attraction of gravity, they are attracted because of charge differences.  You have to have a fair bit of mass to produce serious attractive forces.  But electrical charge can pull lightweight things together.

This is the case for your asteroids.  Because of their composition and the fact that they are whacking into each other and rubbing against each other, many of the asteroids have acquired electrical charge.  They attract each other and so remain in a cloud.  Perhaps a solar wind inputs energy and charge as well, keeping the assembly dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is what you are asking for, but I have it like this in my space horror novelette:

Hero's planet was cut off from civilization for 1000 years . In reality, most of the humanity was destroyed by bio-engineered virus  - aliens just overlooked this little colony and with little bit of luck, supply ship never arrived and virus never got there. It took the colony 1000 years to built themselves back to interstellar technological level (they had knowledge, just not resources). Hero one day found another shard of human leftovers - mining and refining space station in asteroid field (It is huge station - where miners and metallurgist lived with their families + required infrastructure). Despite being dead, the station operated for next 500 years and while no FTL ship was available they had at least short-range vessels and pulled near asteroids together and used them for whatever they needed. For expanding station, fuel, spare parts etc. Over 500 years the Mining station accumulated thousands of various asteroids in huge cluster around station - the field in my settings is really small - just a bubble in diameter 100,000km. But perhaps you could use this idea and make it as a some huge junkyard or storage field for mining facility - perhaps even whole ring around some industrial planet. They just pre-stocked asteroids. *Sorry I love One-Product Planet and Planet of the Hats trope so I use it a lot haha*

Answer (score 1):

If these object don't have to be asteroids but could also be comets, there is a simple mechanism by which you could end up with a trail of many comets.

A comet can break up into many pretty large fragments as it passes near the Sun. Those fragments will all have almost identical orbits, so they will be very near one another (see for instance the [Levy-Shoemaker comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Shoemaker%E2%80%93Levy_9)).

You don't say how big the field has to be, but this might be one option.

Answer (score 1):

Very recently there was an Earth-shattering kaboom, and now there's 6×10²⁴ kilograms of junk out there. It's mostly all moving away from the center of mass of the planet, and it's all superheated and glowing white-hot. Gradually it will spread out and form a ring, but it will be millions of years before the collisions become rare.